# Custom admin form error "need more than 1 value to unpack"

Tags: django, django-admin

I have been adapting this article [How to Add Custom Action Buttons to Django Admin](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin-8d266f5b0d41) to my particular circumstance and things are working pretty well except for this one strange error I am getting. In my `forms.py` I have defined `class DenyForm`: (Note the `request` parameter in `form_action` is not the usual API request. I have a model `class Request`.) What should form_action be returning?

```
class DenyForm(ApproveOrDenyForm):

    def form_action(self, request, admin_approver ):
        print "forms DenyForm Called."
        justification = self.cleaned_data['justification']
        request.admin_deny(admin_approver=admin_approver,justification=justification)
        return [request]
        #return request.admin_deny(admin_approver=admin_approver,justification=justification)
```

This results in a message of

```
“‘Please correct the errors below.’ need more than 1 value to unpack”.
```

I have tried different endings to my form_action method. If my last line is:

```
return request
```

I get `“‘Please correct the errors below.’ ‘Request’ object is not iterable”.`

If the last line is:

```
return request.admin_deny(admin_approver=admin_approver,justification=justification)
```

I get this … `“‘Please correct the errors below.’ ‘NoneType’ object is not iterable”`. That is because `admin_deny()` does not return anything. What should `form_action` be returning?

Update: Here is the code that call `form_action()`:

```
class ApproveOrDenyForm(forms.Form):
    justification = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea,
    )

    def save(self, req, login ):
        try:
            user = User.objects.filter(login=login).get()
            req, action = self.form_action(req, user )
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = str(e)
            self.add_error(None, error_message)
            raise
        return req, action
```

Comment: Show us the code that is calling `form_action()` please.

Comment: Thanks @solarissmoke I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `form_action` you are expecting it to return an iterable of two items - `req` and `action`. So you need to ensure that `form_action()` returns a list or tuple of exactly those two things.

It is not clear to me from the post you linked to, or your code, what the `action` returned is supposed to be - maybe just a result of the action performed. You need to check that to decide whether your action method needs to return something else.

Something like this should work:

```
def form_action(self, request, admin_approver ):
    justification = self.cleaned_data['justification']
    action = request.admin_deny(admin_approver=admin_approver, justification=justification)
    # action will be None if admin_deny does not return anything, 
    # but the code calling this function expects it, so return it anyway.
    return (request, action)
```